# useradd with 755 permissions

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, unix, user-management

I d like to set the home directories permissions as 755 when i add the user via useradd.

How can i do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the UMASK parameter in /etc/login.defs:

> UMASK (number) The  permission mask is
>   initialized to this value. It is used
>   by useradd and newusers for creating
>   new home directories.  If  not
>   specified, the permission mask will be
>   initialized to 0077.

(from `man login.defs`)

This is a mask, so the default of 0077 will give you home directory permissions 700, 0022 will give 755.

Interestingly, OpenSuse uses 0022 by default.

If you want to change the default permissions for the files your users create in their home directories, you need the `umask` command. This can be run from /etc/profile for example.

Comment: using the /etc/profile or /etc/bashrc as mentioned, it's also best to restrict things to a certain group of users (mainly so that you don't screw up root), ala:

if [ `id -gn` = mygroup ]; then
  umask 0002
fi

This would set all members of 'mygroup' to have 0775/0664 perms upon login, handy for dev servers where code is shared by a group of engineers.

Answer (score 7):

I know its a quite old post, however:

useradd -K UMASK=0077

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the answer for your question :

```
/etc/login.defs
```

here you can define default values for useradd.

--
Regards,
Robert

Comment: If this is not the way you wanted then probably only some shell script will resolve your prorblem.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a wrapper utility script that calls both useradd and chmod.

But why would you want this? People expect /home/username to be private. It probably would be better to give a separate, shared directory to each user.

Comment: :) I m aware of suggestion. I just want to do it like this for some purpose. sorry but i dont like the script idea.

Answer (score 0):

You could use ''adduser'' after editing the /etc/adduser.conf file and setting DIR_MODE=0755. That's opposed to ''useradd'' There are various customisations that you can do in /etc/adduser.conf.

What linux are you using. Ubuntu has ''adduser''.