# Messed up homedir permissions from useradd command

Tags: useradd

For some reason adding new user with "useradd" create the homedir but with really messed permissions - 002. You read it correct only WRITE permissions for Others. 
Can someone point me what could have caused this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the droid you are looking for is in /etc/login.defs

the umask value should be 002 or 022 (Permissions 775 or 755 for directories).

[enter link description here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37194/why-is-the-default-umask-value-for-useradd-in-opensuse-set-to-022)

[enter link description here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/understanding-linux-unix-umask-value-usage.html)

[enter link description here](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/it-security/managing-default-unix-file-permissions-with-adduser-and-umask/)

[enter link description here](https://www.tecmint.com/add-users-in-linux/)

[enter link description here](https://serverfault.com/questions/98842/useradd-with-755-permissions)

Cheers.